# How can I access two XML elements with the same Name using SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to parse an XML which is some ocassions have elements with the same name tag. For example:

```
<Event Region="xxx" RegionName="xxx">
<Id>xxx</Id>
<Name>xxx</Name>
<Price Name="V" ProductMessage="" ServiceCharge="xx">xx</Price>
<Price Name="A" ProductMessage="" ServiceCharge="xx">xx</Price>
<URL>xxx</URL>
<Date>xxx</Date>
<GMTOffset>-x</GMTOffset>
<StartTime>xx</StartTime>
<EndTime>xxx</EndTime>
</event>
```

In this case `Price` is repeated, in some others there is just one `Price`. 
Is there any way to retrieve the count of `Price` and access each individually?

Thanks for any tip!

Comment: Do you mean `...->Price[0]` and `...->Price[1]`?

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I tried that and din't work so I thought there must be some other way. That is how I should access each one? For example `$event->Event[$i]->Price[0]` ?

Comment: That syntax [should work](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5485). Perhaps your code is not correct :-?

Comment: For example if I call `$event->Event[$i]->Price` I get the correct number but if I call `$event->Event[$i]->Price[0]` I get an empty string. Thats strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data); //Where $data represents your XML string
foreach($xml->Price as $price) echo (string)$price . '<br>';
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason this one works while the other code doesn't. I will keep investigating why the other approach is not working

Comment: One of the big tricks with SimpleXML is typecasting the output so you get the value of the element instead of the object holding the element.

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php#example-5485), you can treat the repeated elements as array items:

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<Event Region="xxx" RegionName="xxx">
<Id>xxx</Id>
<Name>xxx</Name>
<Price Name="V" ProductMessage="" ServiceCharge="xx">a</Price>
<Price Name="A" ProductMessage="" ServiceCharge="xx">b</Price>
<URL>xxx</URL>
<Date>xxx</Date>
<GMTOffset>-x</GMTOffset>
<StartTime>xx</StartTime>
<EndTime>xxx</EndTime>
</Event>');

echo $xml->Price[0] . PHP_EOL;
echo $xml->Price[1] . PHP_EOL;
```

```
a
b
```

(I've fixed your data sample to make it valid XML.)